# JavaScript not removing listener when reading from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, events

Below I have a small JavaScript file that is designed to create elements for each array in the array. All works fine, apart from the last function, `removeEventListeners()`. This function doesn't return any errors, but it simply doesn't remove the listener.

Really appreciate any help! Thanks.

```
var array = [["Bob", 17, 1], ["Alan", 16, 1], ["Dave", 19, 1], ["Terry", 5, 1], ["Janet", 23, 0]];
var elements = [];
var AGE = 1;

function createHandler(i) {
  return function() {
    // Upon clicking the element show an alert with the age of that element (taken from array)
    alert(array[i][AGE]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    elements[i] = document.createElement("div");
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", createHandler(i), false);
}

// This function is where the problem lies - it doesn't remove the handlers
function removeEventListeners() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].removeEventListener("click", createHandler(i), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's because you're passing unique function objects when you `add` and `remove`. To remove a listener, you need to pass the *same* function object you passed when you added, which means you need to reference it somewhere.

Comment: Something you may want to consider is that DOM elements are objects to which properties can be added. If all you're doing is storing a number, you could add it directly to the element. That way instead of creating a unique handler for each element, you can name and reuse the same one, and therefore have a reference to it when you want to remove it from an element. If the property you add to the element is `my_index`, then in the handler, you'd do `array[this.my_index][AGE]`. I wouldn't reference large amounts of data, or other elements, but small things like numbers aren't a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `creatHandler` always returns a *new* function and not the same one you attached. You should store the handlers and fetch them when you want to remove them.

```
var handlers = [];
function createHandler(i) {
    if (!handlers[i]) {
        console.log('Created ' + i);
        handlers[i] = function () {
            alert(array[i][AGE]);
        };
    }
    return handlers[i];
}
```

You can see it in action too: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/TQxua/

Comment: Ahh I see. I think I know what you mean, would you mind providing an example with your answer just to make sure? Thanks